# Why TextBlock is not sizing to its content?

Tags: wpf

Why is the following `TextBlock` not sizing to its content? Its width (as shown with blue backgroud) is covering the width of the entire window.

What am I missing here and how can I fix it?

I have set `Width="Auto"` for the textblock. NOTE: I don't want to set the entire window to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` since it would have other controls that we don't need to use this setting for. This is just a minimal demo for this post only:

```xml
<Page x:Class="WPTEST.HomePage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_TEST"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="HomePage">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Width="Auto" FontSize="16" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Welcome To Home Page. Your home page to perform main tasks"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainWindow Display**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`. The default value is `"Stretch"`, which means that the control should be stretched to fill the space available in the containing element. Setting to `"Left"` will disable that behavior and allow the `TextBlock` to grow only as much needed to fit the text:

```xml
<Grid>
  <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               FontSize="16" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"
               Text="Welcome To Home Page. Your home page to perform main tasks"/>
  </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was a typo...still had "stretch" on the brain when I typed that. Fixed now.